# Quick-Time Event Using a GUI in Java

Tags: java, swing, thread-sleep

I am making an choose-your-own-adventure project with multiple outcomes. One of the things I'm trying to do is incorporate quick time events (QTEs), or those events in games where you have to, say, click a button within a short time limit or you get killed. In this case, I'm trying to make it so that when the time comes, the game says "Suddenly you hear the clopping of hooves coming from your right!", at which point a method is called up that make a GUI pop up with a button, and you only have a few seconds to click the button. If you click the button within the proper amount of time, it should continue with the game (starts with 'CRACK!!'). If not, the game should be over, and a message is printed ('GAME OVER - You were slain by Minotaur Prison Guard.  However, when I run it, the GUI doesn't pop up, the Game Over message prints three times with the sleepLines delay, and then the 'CRACK!! You quickly turn...' message appears.  Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import java.awt.Container;

    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;


    public class KCP1Main extends JPanel{

    public static JButton AttackButton;
    static Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    static int quicktimecompletion = 0;


    public static void main(String[] args)  throws InterruptedException {

        //insert leading up to this point here

        System.out.println("Suddenly, you hear the clomping of hooves to your right!");


        QuickTimeEvent(args);

        sleepLines(500,2);
        System.out.println("CRACK!!");
        sleepLines(1000,1);
        scrollText("You quickly turn right, swinging your metal pole at the same time... it  swings into the head of ");
        scrollText("a minotaur that was charging towards you, with enough force to knock him out.");


    }

}



public static void QuickTimeEvent(String[] args)  throws InterruptedException
{



    for(int timer=0 ; timer<3 ; timer++){

        ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();

        AttackButton = new JButton("<!");
        //static add(AttackButton);
        AttackButton.addActionListener(handler);

        sleepLines(1000,1);

        if(quicktimecompletion == 1)
        {
            break;
        }

        if(timer > 3);
        {

            System.out.println("GAME OVER");
            System.out.printf("You were slain by a Minotaur Prison Guard.");

        }

    }

}

public static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getSource() == AttackButton)
        {
            quicktimecompletion = 1;

        }
    }
}



public static void scrollText(String message) throws InterruptedException{

    for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++)
    {
        System.out.print(message.charAt(i));
        Thread.sleep(62);
    }
    System.out.print("\n");

}

public static void JPanel(String[] args){

    JFrame theGUI = new JFrame();
    theGUI.setTitle("Incoming!");
    KCP1Main makeButtons = new KCP1Main();
    theGUI.add(makeButtons);
    theGUI.setSize(300, 200);
    theGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    theGUI.setBackground(Color.red);

    Container pane = theGUI.getContentPane();

    theGUI.setVisible(true);


}


public static void sleepLines(int duration, int lines) throws InterruptedException{

    for(int i=0; i < lines; i++){

        Thread.sleep(duration);
        System.out.println("");

    }

}

    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the bluntness, but this looks like random stream of consciousness code created by someone in too much of a hurry to read a tutorial. Take my advice, scrap this code, all of it, choose whichever GUI library you wish to use, be it Swing or the more recent JavaFX, and then first study the tutorials before trying to create a complex program with the library. You will save yourself (and us) a lot of grief if you follow this.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the fact that Swing is single threaded, this means that any action which blocks Event Dispatching Thread (like `Thread.sleep`) will prevent it from processing any new events (including paint events) until it unblocks.

Two golden rules...

1. Don't block the EDT
2. Don't update the UI from outside the EDT

In your case, you could achieve your desired result by making use of a Swing `Timer`

See [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

In the back of my head, I'd consider probably making some kind of QTE class, which took the amount of time, a reference to the button the user needs to click and possible some kind of listener/observer/callback.

The QTE would then attached an `ActionListener` to the button, that if triggered, would stop the `Timer` and notify the observer of success.  Otherwise if the `Timer` triggered first, it'd notify the observer of failure.

As an idea

Comment: I must have missed the meeting where we're not suppose to help people :(

Comment: It's less like a meeting and more like the floor of a stock exchange.